# XSL: Construct an Array from a delimited String attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Input:

```
<response>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-custom-link"/>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-general-link"/>
   <style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
   <style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-native-style"/>
   <style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-native-sheet"/>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <bool name="zkConnected">true</bool>
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">0</int>
   </lst>
   <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" numFoundExact="true">
      <doc>
         <str name="roomTypes">room1,room2,room3,room4</str>
         <str name="name">Hotel-A</str>
         <str name="type">hotel</str>
      </doc>
   </result>
</response>
```

I want to use the split function (http://exslt.org/str/functions/split/index.html) to split roomTypes string to an array of strings.
My XSLT doc is as follows-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xml-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" media-type="application/json" />
  
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(response/result[@name='response']/doc)"/>
  
  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
     <!-- <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($input)"/> -->
  </xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="response">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>"results": </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="$count"/><xsl:text>,"hotelDetails":[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="result[@name='response']/doc">
        <xsl:text>{"type":"</xsl:text>  <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='type']" /><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>,"name":"</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="str[@name='name']" /><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>

        <xsl:text>,"roomTypes":[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="array1" select="split('str[@name='roomTypes']', ',')"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$array1">
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:variable name="room" select="."/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$room"/>
                <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>

        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]}</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I keep getting 500 error stating  Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(split, [literal-expr.....

Comment: just declaring exslt namespaces ist not sufficent, you need to download exslt string module and import it.

Comment: You seem to be using a processor that supports XSLT 3.0 - and therefore is not likely to support EXSLT functions, even if you used proper syntax. Use the native tokenize() function instead.

Comment: Your stylesheet is an odd combination of mixing XSLT 3 stuff like `name="xsl:initial-template"` with EXSLT (which is an extension for XSLT 1 processors). It is not clear why you would want to use EXSLT if you really use an XSLT 3 processor. If you want to use the `str:split` function from EXSLT with an 1.0 processor that supports it (Xalan?), then you need to declare the right namespace `xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"`.